# summation of difference between two vectors matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two acceleration vectors, between which i am supposed to find the relative error using the following formula:

Relative_error=(1/n)*sum (abs (a_s-a_m)/a_m)
and the summation is defined between the interval 1:n
a_s is the simulated acceleration and a_m is the measured acceleration

I have tried the following code but doesn't seem to work

```
for i=1:n; 

    re_1=abs(simulated_suspended_mass_acc(i)-cushion_base_acc(i))/cushion_base_acc(i)
    result=(1/n)*sum(re_1(1:n))

end
```

I have even tried cumsum and symsum. Again no positive results.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `Relative_error=(1/n)*sum(abs(a_s-a_m)./a_m)`?

Comment: It returns a NaN value, it is possible to find the summation of individual vectors and then use it individually?

Comment: Does your data start (or end) with both a_s and a_m equal to zero?  If so, the result will be NaN and the resulting sum will be NaN.  You can only included points where a_m is not equal to zero.

Comment: Yes, my acceleration data starts with a zero's. I deleted that section of the signal. The code works fine. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the calculation of the result outside of the loop and a small modification should help, if I understand your problem correctly:

```
single_errors = zeros(n,1); %Preallocate a length n vector to store the error at each point in the interval

valid_n = 0;

for i=1:n; 
    single_errors(i)=abs(simulated_suspended_mass_acc(i)-cushion_base_acc(i))/cushion_base_acc(i);

    % You can add a check for NaNs in the loop with an easy if statement and try to do corrections

    if isnan(single_errors(i))
        single_errors(i) = 0;
    else
        valid_n = valid_n + 1; % One more valid value in the vector
    end
end

result=(1/valid_n)*sum(single_errors); 
%Division over valid_n to get the average value only for the valid values (not NaN)
```